# Determine color used by plotly when color is mapped

Tags: r, plotly

I can use the `colors` argument to provide a color palette for my `plotly` chart like this:

```r
library(plotly)
library(viridis)

col_pal <- viridis(10)

plot_ly(mtcars) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~ mpg, y = ~ cyl, color = ~ factor(cyl), colors = col_pal,
            type = "scatter", mode = "markers", marker = list(size = 25))
```

This will produce the following plot:
[image: Plotly Scatterplot with three lines of differntly colored points]

Using the following `JavaScript` I can determine which colors are effectively used:

```js
const cols = $('path.point').map(function() {
  const style = $(this).attr('style');
  const fill_col = style.match(/fill: [^;]+/g)[0].replace('fill: ', '');
  const hex = '#' + fill_col
    .slice(4, -1)
    .split(',')
    .map(x => (+x).toString(16).padStart(2, 0))
    .join('');
  return hex;
})

new Set(cols)
// Set(3) {'#440154', '#25908c', '#fde725'}
```

If I compare that to `col_pal`:

```r
col_pal
# [1] "#440154FF" "#482878FF" "#3E4A89FF" "#31688EFF" "#26828EFF" "#1F9E89FF"
# [7] "#35B779FF" "#6DCD59FF" "#B4DE2CFF" "#FDE725FF"
```

I see that `plotly` uses the first and the last element (`#440154FF` / `#FDE725FF`), and that the third color seems to be an interpolation of some sorts as it is not directly a member of `col_pal`:

```r
scales::show_col(c(col_pal[1:5], "#25908CFF", col_pal[6:10]))
```

My guess that the color is an interpolation of `col_pal[5:6]`

[image: Plot with 11 tiles showing different colors]

But I have no idea of how the color is calculated? Any ideas how I could replicate the colors `plotly` uses in R knowing:

1. The original color palette
2. The number of colors used in plotly (here `nlevels(as.factor(mtcars$cyl))`)

---

P.S.: If my palette would contain a middle point, the color is exactly matched (change `col_pal <- viridis(11)`, and the colors used are `col_pal[c(1, 6, 11)]`. However, I am really interested in any combinations of oclor palette length and needed colors.

Comment: I looked briefly into `plotly`'s source code but couldn't locate where the interpolation happens. Using e.g. `colorRampPalette` for interpolation (`colorRampPalette(col_pal[c(5, 6)], space='Lab')(3)`) yields a very similar color to what `plotly` uses: `#248F8B`. Is it really necessary for you to know what `plotly` does or would it be feasible to always provide it with a palette whose length matches the number of your factor levels?

Comment: Fair point, and in fact in my application I solved it this way (i.e. matching `length(colors) == length(pal)`) (another way would be looking at JSON object from `plotly_json` and extract the relavant colors).  However, I was interested in general how the interpolation is done. Think of a continuous colorscale and you want to match an arbitrary point. Having said that, if you post your solution, I will be very happy to accept it.

Comment: I don't think my solution answers what you actually asked (what `plotly` does) so I'll better keep it just as a comment. Your answer, on the other hand, does exactly what you wanted so IMHO that should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some debugging I identified the [lines in which the color mapping](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/blob/d76e87e573a5317100d3bcf1cea2b8cb6c1d3c93/R/plotly_build.R#L787) is done (actually already on the R side):

```r
colScale <- scales::col_factor(pal, levels = names(pal) %||% lvls, na.color = na.color)
```

Thus to get exactly the colors used by `plotly` we need to run:

```r
lvls <- levels(as.factor(mtcars$cyl))
scales::col_factor(col_pal, levels = lvls)(lvls)
# [1] "#440154" "#25908C" "#FDE725"
```